# Как сверстать данный элемент?

Tags: html, css

Как сверстать такой элемент, чтобы линия была на всю ширину?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: оба варианта решают вопрос , даже делать не буду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Десяток вариантов можно использовать, но попробуйте например так:

```css
hr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 0px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -28px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<br />
<br />
<br />
<hr />
<span>Text</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

Вот так

```css
.test {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.test:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #555555;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.test span {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"><span>TEST</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

div::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0px;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 border: 1px solid rgb(48,48,48);
}

div::after {
 content: attr(title);
 background-color: rgb(48,48,48);
 padding: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 border-radius: 6px;
 min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div title="TEST"></div>
```